# How to search for a specific kind of qt gui control

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, iteration, state, qcheckbox

I have a `QWidget` that contains a `QGroupBox`, which contains `QComboBox`, `QLineEdit` and `QCheckBox`.

I need to go around all the controls, and if the control is a `QCheckBox`, ask if it is checked or not. I need to know how all the `QCheckBox` are checked - the idea could be something like this:

```
count = 0
for control in groupbox.controls():
    if control is type of QtGui.QCheckBox:
        if control.isChecked:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print('no checked')
    else:
        print('no QtGui.QCheckBox')
print ('there are '+ str(count)+ 'checked')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkboxes are all children of the groupbox, then you can try this:

```
count = 0
for checkbox in groupbox.findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox):
    if checkbox.isChecked():
        count += 1
print('there are %s checked' % count)
```

The checkboxes will be children of the groupbox if they were created like this:

```
checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox('Title', groupbox)
```